# Partial SQL Server database synchronization

Tags: sql-server, data-synchronization

I have 2 SQL Server databases and they have somewhat different schemas.
But there is a table with person attributes.
Name, address, city, email, etc...
And an account key.  on both tables.
Can SQL Server be set up to sync just these attributes.  On this table?
And not the entire database?
And, is there a way to log when data is overwritten from db1 to db2.  or db2 to db1?

Comment: Your best bet is utilizing `MERGE`. [Here is a previously answered question with the relevant information needed to learn more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613983/sql-server-synchronizing-2-tables-on-2-different-databases)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real-time sync you can use replication and select only that table as an article. If you don't need real-time sync and let's say you only need to sync the table once a day, you can create a job scheduled as you need and this job will execute an SSIS package that will move the data from one table to the other.